# Spring MVC + AngularJS - 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I had this working until i added a Department attribute in my Employee model for my OneToMany and ManyToOne relation for database. 
This is the java controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addemployee" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void>addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee empl, UriComponentsBuilder uBuilder){
    System.out.println(empl);
    employeeDao.addEntity(empl);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(uBuilder.path("/addemployee/{id}").buildAndExpand(empl.getEmp_id()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

i also tried adding

```
consumes = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
```

as I seen in other similar questions but that didn't work.

Here is my angular service method:

```
addEmployee: function(employee){
        return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/project/addemployee',employee).then(
                function(resp){
                    console.log('added empl')
                    return resp.data;
                },
                function(error){
                    alert('Error adding employee');
                    return $q.reject(error);
                }
        );
    },
```

and this is angular controller method for adding:

```
this.addEmployee = function(employee){
    EmployeesService.addEmployee(employee).then(
            this.getAllEmployees,
            function(error){
                console.log('error adding employee'+employee);}
    );

};
```

I don't have any exceptions on server-side, only

```
POST http://localhost:8080/project/addemployee 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

in browser's console

Comment: And how does your `employee` object look like? On frontend side?

Comment: this.employee={emp_id:null,first_name:'',last_name:'',email:'',dep_id:null,salary:''};

Comment: i just made my Employee class from the backend without the Department dependency and it's now created only by primitive types but I still get 415 even though before it worked that way ....

Comment: And how `employee` object from backend looks like when you serialize it via some API like Faster XML? Because, that's what your backend code is expecting when it tries to consume JSON coming from frontend.